# Possible to show jQuery autocomplete's dropdown while searching?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I would like to be able to show a loading icon **in** the autocomplete dropdown while the searching is happening.  How can I go about doing this?

Current code:

```
$("#searchbox").autocomplete({
  search: function(event, ui) {
    $('ul.ui-autocomplete').append("<li id='loading_icon'></li>");
    $('ul.ui-autocomplete').show();
  },
  open: function(event, ui) {
    $('#loading_icon').hide();
  }
 ...
```

But what happens is the icon shows at the very top left of the browser page.  The computing of the location hasn't happened yet.  Can i somehow make a call to compute the location of the autocomplete dropdown box?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is doable, but you'll have to convert your `source` option to a function and make the AJAX request yourself. For example:

```
$("#selector").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        /* Show the loading indicator while a search is in progress */
        response([{ label: "Loading...", loading: true }]);
        $.ajax({
            url: "your_url_here",
            data: request,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json"
        }).success(response);
    },
}).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    var $li = $("<li></li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
        .appendTo(ul);

    /* Make sure nothing happens when you click "Loading" */
    if (item.loading) {
        $li.find("a").on("click", false);
    }
};
```

The last bit that overrides `_renderItem` is doing so so that we can cancel the click event of the loading item (and prevent it from being placed in the `input`).

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/m3MGH/

---

*Update, per comment below:*

To show a loading image in a `div`, you could do something like this (just changing the `_renderItem` function):

```
.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    var $li = $("<li></li>");

    if (item.loading) {
        $li.append("<div>Loading<img src='my_loading_img' /></div>").appendTo(ul);                
    } else {
        $li.data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
    }

    return $li;
};
```

You'll probably have to use a little CSS to get things positioned just right, but this should get you started.

Comment: Instead of using the label "Loading...." Is it possible to put in a div with an image? If so, how do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

This did not work for me initially. The changes I had to make to get mine working was to override the _renderItemData class rather than the _renderItem class, and return the $li object.

```
element.autocomplete({
               ...
     }).data("autocomplete")._renderItemData = function (ul, item) {
          var $li = $("<li></li>")
          .data("item.autocomplete", item)
          .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
          .appendTo(ul);

                        /* Make sure nothing happens when you click "Loading" */
          if (item.loading) {
              $li.find("a").on("click", false);
          }
          return $li;
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
if (item.loading) {
    $li.find("a").on("click", false);
}
```

isn't enough, since jQuery auto-complete reacts on the pressing Tab and Enter buttons in the same way as on mouse click. Also auto-complete reacts on Up and Down buttons.

Could anyone suggest solution to fix this behavior?